# Tomcat: Invalid content was found starting with element 'packageScan'

Tags: eclipse, spring, xsd, tomcat7, apache-camel

I am creating the following Camel configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

      <routeContextRef ref="DoItRoute"/>

      <onException id="OnException">
         <exception>java.sql.SQLException</exception>
         <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
         <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0" />
         <to id="ErrorProcessor"                                  uri="bean:errorProcessor"/>
      </onException>

      <packageScan>
         <package>com.myself.route.doit</package>
         <excludes>*ExcludeMe*</excludes>
      </packageScan>

    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

In Eclipse, when I hover over `<camelContext`, it tells me

```
Element : camelContext
Content Model : (routeContextRef? | onException? | packageScan?)*
```

So my configuration seems to follow the schema.

However when I deploy it to Tomcat, I am getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 23 in XML document from class path resource
>   [META-INF/spring/my-route.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 20;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'packageScan'. One of
>   '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":onException,
>   "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":onCompletion,
>   "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":intercept,
>   "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":interceptFrom,
>   "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":interceptSendToEndpoint,
>   "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":restConfiguration,
>   "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":rest,
>   "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":route}' is expected.

What is going on here? Eclipse and Tomcat look at different XSD's?
how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order matters!!.. Try to rearrange the tags as below , It will work.

```
 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">              

     <packageScan>
         <package>com.myself.route.doit</package>
         <excludes>*ExcludeMe*</excludes>
      </packageScan>

      <routeContextRef ref="DoItRoute"/>

      <onException id="OnException">
         <exception>java.sql.SQLException</exception>
         <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
         <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0" />
         <to id="ErrorProcessor"                                  uri="bean:errorProcessor"/>
      </onException>      

    </camelContext>
```

@refer http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.15.0.xsd. (Tag sequence can be identified here)

Comment: You are absolutely right! I should have checked the XSD. Thanks a million!